# How to select top-of-the values from database with minute resolution

Tags: php, mysql, select

I have a mysql(i) databse that is written to every minute (usually 4 or 5 seconds after the minute).

I would like to select the values that are cleset to top-of-the-hour for the last 36 hours and I've no idea how to do it.

I've been playing with INTERVAL and DATE_ADD but have not found something that works yet. Any help would be appreciated.

[image: Here's one of the rows that I'd like to select]

**Edit:**

Extra info:
*Table name:*
temperature
*Column names:*
uid (AI)
time (timestamp)
probe0
probe1
probe2
probe3
probe4

Perhaps it would also be better to be
now
now -1hour
now -2hours
etc
now -36hours

FWIW, I'm currently using the following code so select ALL the data for the last 36 hours (2160 rows)

```
SELECT time, probe0, probe1, probe2, probe3, probe4 FROM temperature WHERE temperature.time >= DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -2160 MINUTE) ORDER BY temperature.time DESC
```

Comment: Did I understood you correct - you want the last value for each hour for the last 36 hours ?

Comment: Will data for all 36 hours always be present or could there be a period where for several hours no reporting occurred and thus not all 36 hours were present?  and since there is no record in that "hour" period" would you still want the record "Closest" to it?  pretend we had no entries in the 13:00:00 hour at all.  Should it be present in the results but list the 12:59 detail?

Comment: @codtex, No, the 1st value for each hour

Comment: @xQbert Good point, there may be unknowns in there as well. The closest fit *may* work. Not 100% sure, I'm busy building a graphing system and need to get the values 1st, once I've got the values, i'll be incorporating the graphing code. don't know how flexible it will be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the first record for each hour you can use MySQL's [**MIN()**](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/aggregate-functions-and-grouping/aggregate-functions-and-grouping-min().php) function and since it is an [**Aggregate Function**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html) you need to use [**GROUP BY**](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp) to group your data by date and hour. So a sample query will look like:

```
SELECT 
    MIN(`time`) as first_for_hour, probe0, probe1, probe2, probe3, probe4
FROM `temperature`
WHERE `time` >= DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -2160 MINUTE)
GROUP BY DATE(`time`), HOUR(`time`);
```

and for reading data 36 hours back I used your WHERE clause:

```
WHERE `time` >= DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -2160 MINUTE)
```

I hope this will be helpful to you and [**here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8e2ded/1) is the playground.

Comment: That's awesome, thanks! Although it seems to be selecting a lot more than it should for some reason, but that's cool i've just included the 'uid' in the select and used `ORDER BY uid DESC LIMIT 36` to make sure that only the last 36 are selected.